# How can i add my custom block in catalog category page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, blocks, catalog

How can i add my custom block in catalog category page

[image]

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
<!-- i add my block here  -->
                    <block type="quickview/quickview" name="quickview" template="quickview/quickview.phtml" />
                </block>                 
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Comment: you can call your block file as $this->getChildHtml('quickview') in list.phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always modify your `phtml` file which displays product listing on **category page**,

Go to below Path
`app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

you can set your custom text according the html structure here...

Comment: i dont want to edit my .phtml file

Comment: any reason ?  this we always do to get our look and feel ?

Comment: i want to do this using reference  Tag

Comment: I don't think you can do that, because from reference tag you always call other block after or before block. this you need within list.phtml.  Experts can verify :)

Comment: @Amit Bera...in which file you will add this code ? as it see it is again code change only.

Answer (score 1):

vaibhav ahalpara,you can do anything without changing at list.phtml;

You want to call this block for all products

echo past the code at

```
    echo   $this->getLayout()->createBlock('quickview/quickview')
->setTemplate('quickview/quickview.phtml')->setName('quickview')->toHtml()
```

and this code id put inside of  `loop of products` thus it can `be show for all products`:

Add this code below `$this->getPriceHtml()`